# <p:ajax listener> on blur event not invoked when <p:inputMask> has a mask

Tags: jsf, primefaces, input-mask

When I use `<p:inputMask>` with a `mask`, then the `<p:ajax listener>` attached to blur event is not invoked. There are no errors in the JS console. I've also tried `<f:ajax listener>`.

This works:

```
<p:inputMask required="true" value="#{bean.value}">
    <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{bean.test}" />
</p:inputMask>
```

```java
public void test() {
    System.out.println("Test");
}
```

Once I set the `mask` attribute, the listener is not invoked:

```
<p:inputMask required="true" value="#{bean.value}" mask="99.999-999">
    <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{bean.test}" />
</p:inputMask>
```

I'm using Mojarra 2.2.3 and PrimeFaces 4.0.

Comment: My p:inputText was an p:inputMask. I changed it because with p:inputMask the ajax's listener is never called.

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you getting any script errors in console? which version of Primefaces and Mojarra are u using?

Comment: Works fine for me in Mojarra 2.2.8 + PrimeFaces 5.0 and 4.0. Try upgrading or otherwise post a MCVE if that piece of code of you was actually not tested in a completely blank playground project with everything set to default unless otherwise mentioned.

Comment: It works in the new blank project I created. Now, on the main project, might it be a lib conflict? Do you have any suggestion where should I take a look at?